# Autocomplete Contact Metadata

Tags: custom-fields

Is there way to autocomplete a contacts metadata using the Advanced Filter option on stock CiviCRM? Let's use a contacts email address as an example. Thank you.

Custom Field Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: I don't understand the question. What screen are you referring to and what are you trying to accomplish? Stating your goal would help, and a screenshot would be nice.

Comment: If you add a custom field, then change the data type to Contact Reference --> Autocomplete-Select. You are able to add custom API commands. I was trying to get it to autocomplete an address or email from a selected contact. I posted a screenshot into my original post.